# Where to store methods in MVC projects

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

In MVC3, where is the best place to store methods

I am currently racking up quite a bit of code in my `HomeController` and feel that my methods should be seperate from the controller logic.

Should I create a model with a class of "HomeControllerMethods" or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an answer https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/981/not-feeling-100-about-my-controller-design discussing a similar topic.

Another great resource is www.tekpub.com  I've just gone through the ASP.NET MVC3 Real World series.  This series goes along at a cracking pace, and Rob uses an Infrastructure folder similar to @tugberk's advice.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely do not put them inside your controllers **if they are not specific to a controler** and if they don't use the properties or methods of that controller.

Put them some other place. Where you need to put them is up to you. I always create another project called `MyApp.Infrastructure`.

Comment: Cool, I am doing this for all the business logic at the moment anyway. It is *kind of* specific to that controller, but I think I'll make it easier to access. Just didn't know if MVC had a set way of doing this already.

Comment: @RawryLions if your methods inside your controller use the controller's resources or specific to your controller then leave them where they are. Personally, I start the method names with lower latter inside my controllers to keep it separate. For Example, `private void registerViewBagForDestinationDropDown() { /*...*/ }`

Comment: Don't make a new project unless you have a physical reason to do so.    If only the web project uses them a folder is perfect and saves you build time.

Answer (score 1):

Well, application architecture is your own choice which must be dictated by your conrete use cases. Try reading about [three tier pattern to begin with](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article71.aspx)